# Question about an integration technique in Tveito-Winther's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I do not understand the last line in the following computation, taken from pgs 40-41 of Tveito and Winther's book *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations: A Computational Approach* [TW]:

> ...we define $$F(y) = \int_0^y f(z) \; dz,$$ and observe that
> \begin{align*}
> \int_0^x \left( \int_0^y f(z) \; dz \right) &= \int_0^x F(y) \; dy \\
> &= [yF(y)]_0^x - \int_0^x y F'(y) \; dy \\
> &= xF(x) - \int_0^x yf(y) \; dy \\
> &= \int_0^x (x - y)f(y) \; dy.
> \end{align*}

It seems as though the "missing steps" connecting the last two lines are:
\begin{align}
\tag{1} xF(x) - \int_0^x yf(y) \; dy &= x\int_0^x f(y) \; dy - \int_0^x f(y) \; dy \\
\tag{2} &= \int_0^x x f(y) \; dy - \int_0^x yf(y) \; dy \\
&= \int_0^x (x - y) f(y) \; dy,
\end{align}
where in (1), I am using the definition $F(y) = \int_0^y f(z) \; dz$, but rewriting it as $F(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \; dy$...if that is allowed, I do not understand why. And then in (2), I am moving the variable $x$ inside the integral sign and, again, if that is allowed I do not understand why.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only difference between $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ is the argument; all you are doing is changing the variable name. I'm not sure why you think that wouldn't be 'allowed'? And in $(2)$ the variable of integration is $y$, so yes you can bring the $x$ inside the integral.

Comment: @mattos I don't know. In partial differential equations, my professor(s) seem to assume I have a lot of knowledge about specific "tricks" of integration at a theoretical level. But I don't remember ever learning these. It's like there's a huge gap of intermediate material between undergrad calculus, which was "solve for x" style", versus graduate analysis which was very theoretical, measure spaces and Lesbesgue integration et cetera. And it is that big gap of intermediate material that I never learned that is exactly the material that PDEs keeps exploiting.

Comment: For example, what is a dummy variable? When can I pass limits into an integral and when can't I? When can I pass derivatives into an integral and when can't I? What the heck is a convolution? And most importantly: WHAT WAS THE CLASS WHERE ALL THIS INTERMEDIATE MATERIAL WAS TAUGHT?? Anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A dummy variable is just the variable used when integrating. Note that $$\int f(x) dx = \int f(y) dy = \int f(;) d ; = \int f(@) d @ = \dots$$ It doesn't matter whether you use $x, y, ;$ or $@$ as the variable of integration. For the next two questions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations) and the links therein. I've never really understood convolutions myself so can't help you there. I suppose it is just expected that you know the intermediate material before going to university. And if you don't (like I didn't) then it is a long hard slog.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the topics mentioned in your comments are quite delicate, and may (or may not) be studied in honors courses in calculus/analysis, but what you have in your main question is much simpler.

It should be familiar from basic calculus that
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(u) \, du = \int_a^b f(t) \, dt = \cdots$$
(since all those integrals represent the same “area below the graph”), and this is what is meant by saying that $x$ (or $u$ or $t$) is a “dummy variable” – it can be replaced by any other currently unused variable without changing the meaning of the expression. And the fact that a formula like $f(y) = y^2$ defines the same function $f$ as the formula $f(x) = x^2$ should be pre-calculus knowledge.

So the formula $$F(y) = \int_0^y f(z) \, dz$$ defines the same function $F$ as the formula $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(z) \, dz$$ (since you have just replaced $y$ with $x$ everywhere), and this is the same thing as $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \, dy$$ (since you have just replaced the dummy variable $z$ with $y$, which is fine now that $y$ isn't used in the formula any longer; note that writing $F(y) = \int_0^y f(y) \, dy$ would generally be frowned upon).

Also, when you're integrating with respect to the variable $y$, the variable $x$ is just like any other constant, and can therefore be freely moved in or out of the integral, just like the factor $2$ in $\int_a^b 2 \cos y \, dy = 2 \int_a^b \cos y \, dy$, for instance.